# Angular2: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

Below is my postData code. All my get requests are working fine. When I do the post request, I am getting "Cannot read property 'post' of undefined"

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(public _http: Http) { }

        postData(id: any) {
        let data = { "jql": id };
                    let body = JSON.stringify(data);
                    console.log(body);
                    return this._http.post('/api/Desk/Tickets/Search', body, { headers: this.getHeaders() })
                        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

Calling function

```
  UserService.prototype.postData(id).subscribe(data=> {
          console.log('In response');
        });
```

Comment: Is this being invoked as a callback? Maybe you are losing the `this` context and need an arrow function or similar.

Comment: Can you share your service code?

Comment: Updated the question with the complete service class and also calling function.

Comment: What is this? `UserService.prototype.postData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this works:

```
UserService.prototype.postData(id).subscribe(data=> {
          console.log('In response');
        });
```

You break the "this" reference inside your service and circumvent the Angular dependency injection. You need to inject your service where you are calling it from and use:

```
_localServiceInstance.postData(...) instead of UserService.prototype...
```

**Update**

@AJT_82 is right, you have the syntax of your function wrong and that messes up the this reference. It should be:

```
legendItemClick: (e) => {
    console.log(this);
    return false;
}
```

This is also crazy unreadable. Define the series with the events an empty object:

```
series: {
    animation: false,
    point: {
        events: {}
    }
}
```

Then after the option declaration or someplace else in your file you can simply assign the event:

```
this.options.plotOptions.series.point.events.legendItemClick = function(e) {
    console.log(this);
    return false;
};
```

Here is a working version:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZJQeGLbz3OkR3mkpqc7j?p=info

Comment: I tried that. In my calling function I couldn't able to create the localservice instance because "this" of class is not available there because highcharts properties are available in "this".

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Can you provide your code where you need to call UserService? You need to inject UserService in the constructor as you do with the HTTP service.

Comment: So basically, in my calling function - I have constructor(private userService: UserService){} and I am having like below. Where this.userService.PostData fails because this is undefined. this property of highchart overrides class this properties.   newfunction(id: any) {
this.userService.postData(id);
       
        UserService.prototype.postDonutData(id).subscribe(dashboardsData => {
          console.log('In response');
        });
    }

Comment: Without knowing what the actual highchart code is that you are using, I can't help you any more than that. Can you create a plunkr of your issue?

Comment: Please have a look at the plnkr.https://plnkr.co/edit/yzXLz7AIDoWa1Pzxxl4k?p=preview.  In legend Item click please have a look at "this" legendItemClick: function (e) {
                               console.log(this);
                                return false;
                            }

Comment: Use fat arrow syntax to keep the scope of `this`: `legendItemClick: (e) => {...`

Comment: You mean something like below.   this:   legendItemClick:  (e => {
                                newfunction(this.id);
                                return false;
                            }); I am getting errors with this.

Comment: @AJT_82 Did you get a chance to see my comment.

Comment: like I wrote before, it should be `legendItemClick: (e) => {...` instead of `legendItemClick: function (e) {` I didn't take a closer look at your code, so I don't know if there are other problems, I just saw that you were using `function` instead of fat arrow syntax in your comment, but hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. this helped resolve the problem. But will this cause an issue in IE?

Comment: I just tried this in IE, seems to work fine. I recommend you decouple the events from the options somehow. If this solves your issue, please accept my answer.

Comment: @BenRichards Thanks. Do we have a similar event when I click on legend title(2000)??

Comment: I don't know. The events are pacific to the charting framework. Look at their documentation to find out what events you can use.